# Md-dialog with bottom sheet triggers vertical scroll

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, bottom-sheet, mddialog

I got a problem with this as I'm only new in using `angularjs` material design. I have a `md-dialog` and I put `bottom sheet` inside of it but the problem is, when the `bottom sheet` appeared it also triggers the vertical scrollbar of the `md-dialog`. Below is the image
[image]

The content of `bottom sheet` cannot be viewed in full unless I scroll it to bottom. I tried to hide the scrollbar using the `overflow:hidden` inside the `md-dialog` but the bottom part of the `bottom sheet` are not shown. Below is my code

`<md-dialog aria-label="Add Acitivity" flex="75" style="overflow: hidden;">`

[image]

How can I solve this sirs? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a question: is it an option to close the dialog before opening the bottom sheet?

Comment: Found any solution ?